# mssql_connect problems

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I've never really used MS server or anything like that before, i have, however used Linux servers before and know what i am doing there.

I have to use a Windows server with MS SQL now, but i haven't a clue how to connect to it with PHP, usually it would be a matter of:

```
    $data = mysql_connect();
```

But this didn't work, so i done a bit of research and found this little number:
        $data = mssql_connect();

This is used for MS SQL database server, well from what i can't see. Anyway the problem is, when i use the first, the 'or die' method kicks in saying that i cannot connect to the database as you would expect. But when i use the second function, nothing happens, as if i have a syntax error.

Any ideas? Any help getting started with MS SQL Server?

Thanks for the time
Brian.

P.S Heres my code just incase i'm being silly and have done something wrong.....

```
     $remotedb_host = "";//Here is the server IP address

     $remotedb_username = "user1"; 

     $remotedb_pass = "example"; 

     //$remotedb_name = "exampletable";

     // Run the connection here 
     $dbhandle = mssql_connect($remotedb_host, $remotedb_username, $remotedb_pass)
         or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server "); 


      echo $dbhandle;

     echo "hello";//this is to test if anything is displayed at all on the page
```

Also i will be remote connecting from a linux server, is this a bad thing to do? should i keep it all on the Windows Server? Does it make a difference in all fairness?

Thanks Again.

Comment: uncomment php_mssql.dll in php.ini ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, about your errors, i recommend adding on top

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will show you all errors that occur.

Make sure you have the mssql extension on in your php.ini file (remove the # sign before mssql.so or the ; sign from the mssql.dll)

Also, try `var_dump()`ing the $dbhandle instead of echoing it.

You could also verify the connection by using the following as stated in the PHP Manual :

```php
if (!$dbhandle) {
    die('Woopsie Daisy!');
}
```

Shai

Comment: Right i can't find anything to do with mssql.dll in my php.ini file, note this is on the linux server i'm trying to change this.... I'm not sure if that will make to much of a difference. I've found the section for MSSQL so if you know of a setting in there that needs to be changed? Could i add this line into the .ini file myself?

Comment: On Linux this file would be called mssql.so , also , did you add the two lines i suggested , which error did you get?

Comment: Do you know where i can find this file? I have added the first to lines for errors and i have also added the new way of handling the die method. I still get a plain white screen as if its not executing anything.

Comment: I think the MSSQL extension is packed with the Sybase extension in some distros.

Comment: That doesn't make alot of sense, it should at least tell you that your extension is not loaded if thats the problem. Anyways could you copy you php.ini and your code to www.pastebin.com ? MsSQL.so should be a part of most distros, Which distribution of linux are u using? (Ubuntu/Centos etc..)

Comment: Its Centos I'm trying to remote log into look around at the moment, but not having the best of time.

Comment: So this isn't your own machine, meaning its hosted somewhere? If so , contact your webmaster and tell him to enable the MsSQL Extension if its not enabled already.

Comment: Well that's a good idea and i can't believe i didn't think of it.... Haha thanks for the help everyone!